# React native isnt inserting new line

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this component that takes some random text and formats that into a well spaced paragraph

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const ProductDescription = ({ text }) => {
  const paragraphs = text.split(/\n\s*\n/); // split text into paragraphs
  const formattedParagraphs = paragraphs.map((paragraph, index) => (
    <Text key={index} style={{ padding:20, marginBottom: 10 }}>
      {paragraph}
    </Text>
  ));

  return <View>{formattedParagraphs}</View>;
};

export default ProductDescription;
```

I am using this way

```
<ProductDescription
  text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eget est leo. Sed fermentum, ante vitae ultricies lacinia, lacus quam sagittis turpis, vitae ultrices magna metus at purus. Nam malesuada diam diam, in faucibus libero consequat eu. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus malesuada nibh vel urna tincidunt malesuada. Nullam nec dolor in neque rutrum bibendum. Proin vel consectetur orci. Ut semper luctus elit, vel tristique ex commodo sed. Vestibulum auctor tortor a lectus egestas, non dignissim justo tincidunt. Suspendisse hendrerit libero vel sapien dictum, ut lobortis ex ultrices. Pellentesque at bibendum sapien. Integer eu mauris eros. Nam sit amet nisl ac nisl aliquam dapibus. Fusce rutrum quam in blandit facilisis."
/>
```

This does not insert any new line whatsoever. How can i format the text to a paragraph format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From first glance, the problem may be that the text you're giving as a prop doesn't pass the regex due to the text being read as plain text. When reproducing your code and applying the lorem ispum text you gave, you're correct, it doesn't split to the next paragraph.

However changing it to:

```
<ProductDesrcription text={`lorem ispum \n ....`} // changed text="..." to text={`...`}
```

causes the component to work properly.

Without wrapping the string in brackets, the " \n " will be read as plain text. So be sure to wrap your string in brackets with back ticks. Also be sure the string actually includes \n.